# Have there been any known "in the wild" exploits of any Google Chrome (Android) 40.0.2214.89 vulnerabilities?

Tags: web-browser, android, chrome

https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-1224/product_id-15031/version_id-179594/Google-Chrome-40.0.2214.89.html

I looked for any news about them and couldn't find anything. Anyone know how dangerous those vulnerabilities are?

Comment: From the link you provided, the only confirmed "dangerous" one is CVE-2015-1211. Searches for "CVE-2015-1211 exploit" returned no results. The CVE score describes how "dangerous" it is. Do these things answer your question? If so, I'll make it an official answer.

Comment: So it looks like there are no known instances of that exploit happening in practice? If there are no practical instances, then that answers the question.

Comment: Using all the typical places to search, there is no public exploit.